# twemoji combines 2 emoticons into one

Tags: unicode, emoji, emoticons

The Unicode Emoticon for D = &#x1F1E9; and E = &#x1F1EA;

The Unicode Emoticon for the German (DE) Flag is &#x1F1E9;&#x1F1EA;

If I have a D and E Emoticon without anything between them then twemoji will combine them into the German flag image. Any idea how to prevent this?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/bb4LLLoy/

```
<p></p>
<span></span>
twemoji.parse($('p')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `U+200C` (ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER) between the characters to prevent them from joining together to form a single grapheme/glyph. In HTML, you can use the entities `&#8204;` or `&zwnj;`.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried it with a space but that didn't look good. This is better.